# Can't scroll iframe in Bootstrap modal on iOS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I made a simple demo to show my problem. This problem occurs only on iOS.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Open modal
</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
          <iframe src="https://tma.ee/test.htm"> </iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  min-height: 350px;
}

.modal-body {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
  overflow-x: auto !important;
}
```

I have tried multiple solutions that have been suggested here on stackoverflow, but none of them have worked for me so far.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MulOnPomm/bvk1dmxt/11/

Full screen for iOS testing: http://fiddle.jshell.net/MulOnPomm/bvk1dmxt/1/show/light/

The iOS emulator I'm using for testing: https://appetize.io/

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084118/webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-css-bug-on-ipad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the option `overflow: scroll;` inside the iframe property in css

```
iframe {
     overflow: scroll;
 width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  min-height: 350px;
}
```

else refer this [link](https://davidwalsh.name/scroll-iframes-ios) or
this [issues](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14839) may help you